# Is there a way I can nest a button inside of a router link, and when it's clicked to only trigger the button instead of both?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

To clarify, I have this router link inside a navbar, which has a button on top of it that changes the route.

Here's code for context:

```
<router-link v-if="foo" :to="/">
...
  <button @click="redirect"> GO </button>
...
```

The method for redirection:

```
redirect() { this.$router.push('/myroute').catch(() => {})
```

I tried using z index on both elements, but every time I click on the GO button it first goes to the '/myroute' and then goes back to '/'

Is there a way I can work around this?

Answer (score 0):

You could call `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent this event being propagated in the bubbling phase. So the event will stop only on the button element.

```
redirect(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.$router.push('/myroute').catch(() => {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **stop** modifier to **@click**.

```
<router-link v-if="foo" :to="/">
...
  <button @click.stop="redirect"> GO </button>
...
```

This is the vue equivalent of stopPropagation.

The z-index is more about the display of the button. Events propagate such that when you click on an inner DOM element, you're also clicking on everything that's at the (x,y) including the containing node. If there's nothing else listening to that event (which is usually the case) then the click does what you want.

Another alternative is to make the button and the router-link siblings, and use an outer `<div></div>` with some flex styling to place them where you want.